# perl hash of arrays issue

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have few lines in my array `@lines` in which `*` shows me the start time of a command (like sync/fetch) and the line with same processID `pid` and the command without `*` shows me the end time. They may not be continuous always. I would like to get the `startdate` and `enddate` of a particular `processID` and `cmd`. Like for `usera` the cmd `sync` with processID `11859` started at `2015/01/13 13:53:01.491-05:00` and ended at `2015/01/13 13:55:01.492-05:00`

Below is my approach in which I took a hash of array and used `processID` as key and did split the lines. This works fine only when the start and end lines of a command are continuous , but how can I make it work even when they are not continuous.

```
my %users;
foreach my $line (@lines) {
   if ($line =~ m{(\*)+}) {
        ($stdate, $sttime, $pid, $user, $cmd) = split ' ',   $line;
        $startdate ="$stdate $sttime";
   }
   else {
     ($eddate, $edtime, $pid, $user, $cmd) = split ' ',   $line;
     $enddate = "$eddate $edtime";
   }           

       $users{$pid} = [ $startdate, $enddate, $user, $cmd ];

    }
```

Content in `@lines`:

```
2015/01/13 13:53:01.491-05:00 11859 usera       *sync_cmd 7f1f9bfff700 10.101.17.111      
2015/01/13 13:57:02.079-05:00 11863 userb       *fetch_cmd 7f1f9bfff700 10.101.17.111
2015/01/13 13:59:02.079-05:00 11863 userb       fetch_cmd 7f1f9bfff700 10.101.17.111
2015/01/13 13:55:01.492-05:00 11859 usera       sync_cmd 7f1f9bfff700 10.101.17.111
```

Comment: @chilemagic: Not blank lines, if line1 has `sync_cmd` starting date , the endingdate for same command and process id may not be line2, it can be in any line.

Comment: Would it not be better to do a hash of hashes for this use-case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm looking at your code and wondering why you're using a hash of arrays.

As far as I'm concerned, the purpose of array is a set of similar but ordered values.

Could you not instead do:

```
my %processes;

foreach (@lines) {
    my ( $date, $time, $pid, $user, $cmd, @everything_else ) = split;

    if ( $cmd =~ m/^\*/ ) {

        #if command starts with a * - it started.
        if ( defined $processes{$pid} ) {
            print "WARNING: $pid reused\n";
        }

        $processes{$pid}{'start_date'} = $date;
        $processes{$pid}{'time'}       = $time;
        $processes{$pid}{'user'}       = $user;
        $processes{$pid}{'cmd'}        = $cmd;
    }
    else {
        #cmd does not start with '*'.
        if ( $processes{$pid}{'cmd'} =~ m/$cmd/ ) {

            #this works, because 'some_command' is a substring of '*some_command'.
            $processes{$pid}{'end_date'} = $date;
            $processes{$pid}{'end_time'} = $time;
        }
        else {
            print
                "WARNING: $pid has a command of $cmd, where it started with $processes{$pid}{'cmd'}\n";
        }
    }
}
```

You might want some additional validation tests in case you've got e.g. a long enough log that pids get reused, or e.g. you've got a log that doesn't include both start and finish of a particular process.

Comment: `*cmd` denotes start and the next coming line with same `pid` and `cmd` denoted the end  of the process.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign to `%users{$pid}` you are presuming that the most recent `$startdate` and `$enddate` are both relevant.  This problem is exacerbated by the fact that your variables that hold your field values have a scope larger than the `foreach` loop, allowing these values to bleed between records.

In the `if` block, you should assign the values of `$startdate, $user, $cmd` to the array.  Individually or as a slice if you like.  In the `else` block you should assign `$enddate` to it's element in the array.

Regex extra credit:  You don't seem to really care if there is more that one `*` in a record, making the `+` in the regex superfluous.  As an added bonus, without it the capturing group is also of no value. `m{\*}` should do quite nicely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but its still not clear for me regarding `else` block. How can I assign `$enddate` to the associated `pid` ?

Comment: `$users{$pid}[1] = $enddate;`  would be my 1st instinct.  Presuming you keep your fields in the same order...